# its showing variable undefined

Tags: codeigniter

**This is My Controller page**

```
class Cart extends CI_Controller{
```

public function index()
      {

```
    $getALlCat  = $this->Product_model-> getAllCategory();
     $data = array();

     //Retrieve cart Data
     $data['cartItems']  = $this->cart->contents();


    //print_r($data);exit;
    //$this->load->view('cart/index' ,$data);
    ///$this->load->helper('url');
 / /$this->load->view('cart/header',['getAllCate'=>$getALlCat], $data);    //including header and 
footer   
    $this->load->view('cart/cartbody',['getAllCate'=>$getALlCat], $data);

    $this->load->view('common/footer');    //including header and footer
  }
}



**This is View page**



<tbody>
                        <?php if($this->cart->total_items() > 0){ foreach($cartItems as $item){    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="<?php echo $item['product_image']; ?>" width="50"/></td>
                            <td><?php echo $item['product_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo '$'.$item["product_price"].' USD'; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center"></td>
                            <td><?php echo '$'.$item["subtotal"].' USD'; ?></td>
                            <td>Are you sue</td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php } }else{ ?>
                        <td colspan="6"><p>Your cart is empty.....</p></td>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>






**Error Showing like this**

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
```

Message: Undefined variable: cartItems

Filename: cart/cartbody.php

Line Number: 217

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\application\views\cart\cartbody.php
   Line: 217
   Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\application\controllers\Cart.php
   Line: 33
   Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\index.php
   Line: 315
   Function: require_once

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple values as an `array key` of `$data` and then send only `$data` to view and use those key to retrieve values. I've rectified your code below and it should work as your needs. I've mentioned comments wherever necessary.

```
 public function index() {

    $data = array();

    $data['getALlCate']  = $this->Product_model-> getAllCategory(); // store it in an array instead (I've changed it to getALlCate from getALlCat, so you don't have to change anything in your view)

    //Retrieve cart Data
    $data['cartItems']  = $this->cart->contents();

    //$this->load->view('cart/header', $data); // including header and footer   
    $this->load->view('cart/cartbody', $data);

    $this->load->view('common/footer');    //including header and footer
  }
}
// you can retrieve data in view by accessing $cartItems and $getALlCate variables.
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$this->load->view('cart/cartbody',['getAllCate'=>$getALlCat, 'cartItems'=> $this->cart->contents()]);
```